# Return type for \newcommand probably doesn't fit \DTLfetch?

Tags: conditionals, datatool, csv, ifthenelse, renewcommand

I want to fetch from the csv file with a boolean condition (either give me the fruit or give me the count). The first command (CMDone) works and says "count" and the fetch also works and says "34". But when I either put the \CMDone in the fetch or within the fetch of \CMDtwo it throws 29 errors and starts to mess with the document (see below).
Also \CMDone gives me "count " with an extra space instead of "count".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{IsAbbreviated}
\setboolean{IsAbbreviated}{false} 

\begin{filecontents*}{fruitdatabase.csv}
fruit , count ,
strawberries, 34
bananas, 10
cherries, 11
apples, 4
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{fruits}{fruitdatabase.csv}


\newcommand{\CMDone}{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{IsAbbreviated}}
        {fruit}
        {count}
}


\newcommand{\CMDtwo}[1]{
    \DTLfetch{fruits}{fruit }{#1}{\CMDone}
}


\begin{document}
\CMDone; \\
\DTLfetch{fruits}{fruit }{strawberries}{count }; \\

\CMDtwo{strawberries};\\
\DTLfetch{fruits}{fruit }{strawberries}{\CMDone}; \\
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: \ifthenelse is not expandable.

Comment: Too bad, is there an alternative or workaround for that?

Comment: they are e.g. expandable tests in etoolbox and in expl3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s comment worked: \ifthenelse is not expandable and deprecated as well but if substituted with etoolbox's \ifbool it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newboolean{IsAbbreviated}
\setboolean{IsAbbreviated}{false} 

\begin{filecontents*}{fruitdatabase.csv}
fruit, count,
strawberries, 34
bananas, 10
cherries, 11
apples, 4
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{fruits}{fruitdatabase.csv}


\newcommand{\CMDone}{\ifbool{IsAbbreviated}{fruit}{count}}
\newcommand{\CMDtwo}[1]{\DTLfetch{fruits}{fruit}{#1}{\CMDone}}


\begin{document}
\CMDone; \\
\DTLfetch{fruits}{fruit}{strawberries}{count}; \\
\CMDtwo{strawberries};\\
\end{document}
```

Additionally the \bool{} has to be removed, it is now just the defined bool name "IsAbbreviated" and the extra space after count vanishes if the whole \newcommand is written in one line.